# Not able to find ohai (~> 6.0) gem in any repository for chef-11.10.0 gem

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

I am trying to install chef as a gem, but due to some firewall issues need to download the .gem file and then build the gem locally in my system. For the chef gem, it requires ohai geim to be preinstalled.
But the version of ohai cannot be found in the rubygems.org site.

chef requires ohai (~> 6.0)

Thoough the ohai installed is 0.6.0, but both seems not to be same.

Comment: Just use the omnibus installer?

Comment: i want the chef gem 6.0 gem sourcecode url

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the download:

- Gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/ohai/versions/6.22.0
- Download: http://rubygems.org/downloads/ohai-6.22.0.gem

If you want the source:

- GitHub: https://github.com/opscode/ohai
- GitHub 6-stable: https://github.com/opscode/ohai/tree/6-stable